# Produce vector of TRUE grepl variables

Tags: r, if-statement, strsplit, grepl

I have this dataset:
http://media.sdsoybean.org/images/Uploads/2016%20South%20Dakota%20Soybean%20Yield%20Contest%20Results.pdf

I want to make a new vector called `Method`.  This will consist of the values `No-till`, `Non-irrigated` or `Irrigated`.  I can extract these from group `Group` column.

I'm thinking an `ifelse()` function combined with `grepl()` or `strsplit()` might work?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you make a self-contained example please? Like `x <- c("Group 0 Non-Irrigated", "Group 0 No-Till")` etc etc... with data representative of each of the possibilities. It's a fair enough question, but it will be useless when the pdf gets moved or deleted.

Comment: I tried this:  `Method <- ifelse(grepl(value1, YieldContests$Group)=="TRUE","No-till",
                  ifelse(grepl(value2, YieldContests$Group)=="TRUE","Non-irrigated",
                         ifelse(grepl(value3, YieldContests$Group)=="TRUE","Irrigated",NA)
                 )
 )`

Comment: Here's the values.
`value1<-"Non-till"
value2<-"Non-irrigated"
value3<-"Irrigated"`

Comment: `sapply(strsplit(YieldContests$Group, " "), tail, 1)` since your values are always at the end of the variable I think